# Why my footer background color doesn't work?

Tags: html, css

```css
#footer {
  background-color: #B40404;
}
#footerleft {
  background-color: #B40404;
  padding: 20px;
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  text-align: left;
}
#footerleft span {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: table;
  color: #F79F81;
}
#footerleft span a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #F79F81;
}
#footerleft span a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FF0000;
}
#footerright {
  background-color: #B40404;
  float: right;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 30%;
}
#footerright span {
  padding: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: table;
  color: #F79F81;
}
#footerright span a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #F79F81;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
  <div id="footerleft">
    <span><a href="#about">About Us</a></span>
    <span><a href="#tours">Tours</a></span>
    <span><a href="#bookings">Bookings</a></span>
    <span><a href="#contact">Contact Us</a></span>
    <span><a href="#southafrica">South Africa</a></span>
    <span><a href="#kenya">Kenya</a></span>
    <span><a href="#special">Special</a></span>
    <span><a href="#feedback">Feedback</a></span>
    <span><a href="#photogallery">Photo Gallery</a></span>
    <span><a href="#help">Help</a></span>
  </div>
  <div id="footerright">
    <span>Phone: 07 1441 2882</span>
    <span>Email: <a href="kibokotravels@gmail.com">kibokotravels@gmail.com</a></span>
    <span>Address: Level 8, 17 Melbourne Street, West End, 4101 QLD.</span>
    <span>BUSINESS HOURS: 9AM - 4PM</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can someone try my code in their computer and let me know if this will work. 
The background color didnt show up when I run in chrome or IE.
Can someone help me figure out whats wrong and help me to find out the wrong point please?

[image: Footer background didnt show up]

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle? -  also what are you trying to achive

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8d2xLj5m/1/ this is working

Comment: Your <div id="footer"> has no height. Try to give a height and you'll see a background color...but as it was asked : what do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: You have to clear the floating elements in your footer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `#footer` background isn't applied because the `#footer` element itself  has a height of `0`, because it only has floating content.

A solution is to ensure the content makes it grow:

```
#footer{
    background-color:#B40404;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

[More information on this problem (and alternate dirty solutions like using `clear: both;`) on Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html)

Answer (score 1):

use **clearfix**

```
.clearfix {
  *zoom: 1;
}

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  display: table;
  line-height: 0;
  content: "";
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}
```

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;    
}

.clearfix {
  *zoom: 1;
}

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  display: table;
  line-height: 0;
  content: "";
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}

#footer {
    background-color: #B40404;
    width: 100%;
    
}
#footerleft {
  background-color: #B40404;
  padding: 20px;
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  text-align: left;
}
#footerleft span {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: table;
  color: #F79F81;
}
#footerleft span a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #F79F81;
}
#footerleft span a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FF0000;
}
#footerright {
  background-color: #B40404;
  float: right;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 30%;
}
#footerright span {
  padding: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: table;
  color: #F79F81;
}
#footerright span a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #F79F81;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer" class="clearfix">
  <div id="footerleft">
    <span><a href="#about">About Us</a></span>
    <span><a href="#tours">Tours</a></span>
    <span><a href="#bookings">Bookings</a></span>
    <span><a href="#contact">Contact Us</a></span>
    <span><a href="#southafrica">South Africa</a></span>
    <span><a href="#kenya">Kenya</a></span>
    <span><a href="#special">Special</a></span>
    <span><a href="#feedback">Feedback</a></span>
    <span><a href="#photogallery">Photo Gallery</a></span>
    <span><a href="#help">Help</a></span>
  </div>
    
  <div id="footerright">
    <span>Phone: 07 1441 2882</span>
    <span>Email: <a href="kibokotravels@gmail.com">kibokotravels@gmail.com</a></span>
    <span>Address: Level 8, 17 Melbourne Street, West End, 4101 QLD.</span>
    <span>BUSINESS HOURS: 9AM - 4PM</span>
  </div>
</div>
```